# How LPI get deviceid from PCIe device and differentiate(same BDF)?

Tags: pci

In Its，how LPI get deviceid from PCIe device and differentiate（EP1 and EP2）？

exampe:
arm64 system
EP1：0000:01:00.0
EP2：0001:01:00.0

EP1 and EP2 deviceid all are 01:00.0

This is description for Deviceid and Eventid:
A peripheral generates an LPI by writing to GITS_TRANSLATER in the ITS. The write provides the ITS
with the following information:

EventID
This is the value written to GITS_TRANSLATER. The EventID idenitifies which interrupt the
peripheral is sending. The EventID might be the same as the INTID, or it might be translated by
the ITS into the INTID.

DeviceID
The DeviceID identifies the peripheral. The manner in which a DeviceID is generated is
IMPLEMENTATION DEFINED. For example, the AXI User signals could be used